# IE8 cache ajaxSubmit

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, submit

I am using the following function to do a image upload/display

The Target is the div where I am updating the content that is returned from the form function. I wanted ajax so I don't have to reload the whole page just to upload and see previews of the image.

I upload a image, display it into the preview, I crop it, and do another function that displays it in a new target (not shown),

The problem is in IE 8 it seems to cache all ajax calls, even though I am setting it not to, the only way to get it to show is a hard refresh. Is there a way to force it to not cache?
This works fine in all other browsers of course.

```
$("#profile-photo").submit(function() {
         var myOptions = {
                        target: '#preview-target',
            beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
                        success: showResponse,
                        clearForm: true,
                        resetForm:true,
                        cache:false

                 };
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(myOptions);
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it's caching the submit, more likely it's caching the image url. In your response, are you just sending back the url for the new image? If so, try appending a query string:

```
<img src="/my/path/to/my/image.jpg?q=12345" />
```

That should force all browsers to re-load the image from the server.

Answer (score 1):

If this concerns a `GET` request, then this is true. If you don't have any option to change it to `POST`, then the best way is to dynamically append an extra query parameter with a timestamp to the URL on every request. In Javascript you could use `new Date().getTime()` for this.